# Swift Combine collect values until last page is found or until time expires

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine, publisher

So I want to collect values until I see the last page, but if the last page never comes I want to send what we have, given a time limit.

I have a way of doing this but it seems rather wasteful. I'm going to be using this to make collections that may have hundreds of thousands of values, so a more space-efficient method would be preferred.

You can copy and paste the following into a playground

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Combine

var subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "Test")

let collectForTime = subj
    .collect(.byTime(queue, .seconds(10)))

let collectUntilLast = subj
  .scan([String]()) { $0 + [$1] }
  .first { $0.last == "LastPage" }

// whichever happens first
let cancel = collectForTime.merge(with: collectUntilLast)
    .first()
    .sink {
        print("complete1: \($0)")
    } receiveValue: {
        print("received1: \($0)")
    }

print("start")

let strings = [
    "!@#$",
    "ZXCV",
    "LastPage", // comment this line to test to see what happens if no last page is sent
    "ASDF",
    "JKL:"
]
// if the last page is present then the items 0..<3 will be sent
// if there's no last page then send what we have
// the main thing is that the system is not just sitting there waiting for a last page that never comes.

for i in (0..<strings.count) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(i)) {
        let s = strings[i]
        print("sending \(s)")
        subj.send(s)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

After playing a bit more with the playground I think all you need is:

```
subj
  .prefix { $0 != "LastPage" }
  .append("LastPage")
  .collect(.byTime(DispatchQueue.main, .seconds(10)))
```

---

I wouldn't use `collect` because under the hood it is basically doing the same thing that `scan` is doing, you only need another condition in the `first` closure eg: `.first { $0.last == "LastPage" || timedOut }` to emit the collected items in case of timeout.

It's unfortunate that `collect` doesn't offer the API you need but we can create another version of it.
The idea is to `combineLatest` the `scan` output with a stream that emits a `Bool` after a deadline (In reality we also need to emit `false` initially for `combineLatest` to start) and `||` this additional variable inside `filter` condition.

Here is the code:

```
extension Publisher {

  func collect<S: Scheduler>(
    timeoutAfter interval: S.SchedulerTimeType.Stride,
    scheduler: S,
    orWhere predicate: @escaping ([Output]) -> Bool
  ) -> AnyPublisher<[Output], Failure> {
    scan([Output]()) { $0 + [$1] }
      .combineLatest(
        Just(true)
          .delay(for: interval, scheduler: scheduler)
          .prepend(false)
          .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
      )
      .first { predicate($0) || $1 }
      .map(\.0)
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

}

let subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

let cancel = subj
  .collect(
    timeoutAfter: .seconds(10),
    scheduler: DispatchQueue.main,
    orWhere: { $0.last == "LastPage" }
  )
  .print()
  .sink { _ in }
```

Comment: After further testing, your answer worked flawlessly. But I need some more time to review

Comment: The update with the append last page won't work because the last page in my project is just an id attached to an item with many values.

Answer (score 1):

I made a small change to your technique

```
import Foundation
import Combine

var subj = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()

let lastOrTimeout = subj
    .timeout(.seconds(10), scheduler: RunLoop.main )
    .print("watchdog")
    .first { $0 == "LastPage" }
    .append(Just("Done"))

let cancel = subj
    .prefix(untilOutputFrom: lastOrTimeout)
    .print("main_publisher")
    .collect()
    .sink {
        print("complete1: \($0)")
    } receiveValue: {
        print("received1: \($0)")
    }

print("start")

let strings = [
    "!@#$",
    "ZXCV",
    "LastPage", // comment this line to test to see what happens if no last page is sent
    "ASDF",
    "JKL:"
]
// if the last page is present then the items 0..<3 will be sent
// if there's no last page then send what we have
// the main thing is that the system is not just sitting there waiting for a last page that never comes.

strings.enumerated().forEach { index, string in
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(index)) {
        print("sending \(string)")
        subj.send(string)
    }
}
```

`lastOrTimeout` will emit a value when it see's `LastPage` or finishes because of a timeout (and emits `Done`).

The main pipeline collects values until the watchdog publisher emits a value and collects all the results.

Comment: I didn't know you can chain timeout and first like that.

Comment: I noticed that the timeout scenario doesn't work without the append(Just("Done")), why is that?

Comment: If you remove `"LastPage"` from the array and add infinite other elements, your solution will never complete because of `timeout` resetting at each emission.

Comment: @FabioFelici I was talking about the append not the first.

Comment: After messing around with this in playgrounds I see the necessity for the append. You need to send the "Done" in order to trigger the condition to stop prefixing.

Comment: @Biclops Sorry I was referring to the whole solution. `append` is needed because `timeout` only completes and doesn't send output so it won't work for `prefix(untilOutputFrom)`

Comment: @FabioFelici Your comments are valid, but it's not clear what the timeout requirements are.  I suspect the solution might be to replace the `collect` in the main pipeline with something like the `.collect(.byTime(queue, .seconds(10)))` from the original post, and remove the `timeout` and `append`

Comment: @ScottThompson I tested your answer and it seems to time out a long time after it said it would.

Comment: @ScottThompson I also noticed an odd things  when testing the `lastPage` scenario. If I removed the timeout and only had the first and append it doesn't always include the last page. I ran into this problem originally in a question I posted the other day. Where I would collect up the last page but not include it. In my tests I only see the last page getting added half of the times.